unsafe-eval in the handlebar.min.js

Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-inline'".

I facing an error while loading handlebar.min.js with the HTTP header, Content-Security-Policy as script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'.
I don't want to use 'unsafe-eval' in the script-src, Where handlebar.min.js requires unsafe-eval to proceed
Seems the below functions used by js which required unsafe-eval to run
>> f(Function.call,k)

>> Function.apply(this,["fn","props","container","depth0","data","blockParams","depths",this.decorators.merge()])

>> Function.apply(this,f))

I'm using the latest version of js (version 4.7.8)
https://s3.amazonaws.com/builds.handlebarsjs.com/handlebars.min-v4.7.8.js
After giving the HTTP Header, Content-Security-Policy as script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' it works. But I need to remove unsafe-eval here

Re-check handlebar installation.
npm list handlebars

if not installed do install handlebars
npm install -g handlebars

also instead of doing runtime compilation do pre pre-compilation
handlebars template.hbs -f template.js

you can temporarily relax your CSP. However, this should not be done in production due to security risks
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';


NPM is not being used to load handlebars. It is being loaded via CDN: https://s3.amazonaws.com/builds.handlebarsjs.com/handlebars.min-v4.7.8.js

then mentions this thing in your question man


It isn't my question. 2) The URL for the import is clearly shown in the question. 3) There is no mention of NPM in the question, so why would you assume it was being used?

